Why were my lead-acid batteries destroyed after operating them in parallel?
I have connected three 12 V lead acid car batteries in parallel to the main car battery in my camper van. After using this system for a few weeks, all three batteries are dead (the voltage drops to below 11 V within a few hours without any load). I would like to understand the exact cause for this to avoid the same thing happening again in my next setup.
Edit: I should probably mention that I was previously running the exact same setup with just one additional battery instead of three. The system worked for many years, and while the capacity was slowly degrading, it was nothing like the very sudden failure of all three batteries that I have experienced now. Since some people are reporting similar experiences (batteries deteriorating quickly when operating them in parallel), but no one gives an explanation that makes sense to me, I would like to specifically understand how connecting three batteries in parallel can lead to such a failure compared to having just one battery in the exact same setup.
Setup and usage
Each of the four batteries is a 12 V 100 Ah lead acid battery, but they are different brands and different ages. All of them worked when I installed them, although they might not all have had their full capacity remaining.
While driving the van, the alternator would charge all 4 batteries. As far as I know, I have a regular 80 A alternator. Since the three additional batteries sit in the back of the van (about 6 m of 16 mm² cable connecting the + poles, a rusty screw connecting to the car chassis for the − pole), there was a significant voltage drop to the back batteries, so they were charging slower than the main car battery.
During the day, the solar panels were also charging all batteries. The maximum charging current on very sunny days (which have not been very frequent) was about 16 A.
While parked, the batteries would be used for lights, various small devices and charging laptops. In addition, sometimes an electric kettle would be used for a few minutes at a time drawing about 80–90 A.
Also while parked, I would often (but not always) turn off the main switch to separate the main battery from the three additional batteries. This would mean that all appliances would only use the three additional batteries, and zero current would be drawn from the main battery. Before starting the car for driving, I would turn on the main switch again.
Thoughts and theories
When searching online about connecting car batteries in parallel, many people seem to have very different theories that often contradict each other. Some people have had the consistent experience that in a setup of two parallel batteries, replacing just one of them would very quickly cause the other one to fail. They say that it is essential to use batteries of the same model and same age. As far as I understand, the main explanation seems to be high equalization currents flowing between the batteries. On the other hand, some people say that 12 V lead acid batteries of any capacity and age can be combined without any issues, unless one of them has a serious defect such as a shorted cell.
From what I have observed about lead acid batteries, it seems to be in their nature that their voltage reacts with a bit of a delay. After disconnecting a charger that was putting them under a voltage of 14.4 V, the voltage only slowly (over the course of several minutes/hours) decreases to whatever the current state of charge is. Similarly, after disconnecting a significant load, their voltage slowly increases for a while. Also, the voltage that a fully charged battery will eventually have after disconnecting it from the charger seems to vary greatly and depends on the health and age of the battery. I have seen anything between 0 and 12.8 V, although for a battery that still works decently the range seems to be between around 12.2 V and 12.8 V.
I can think of various situations where they equalization currents would occur in my setup:

When I turn on the main switch before starting the car, currents would run from the still fully charged main battery into the additional batteries.
When the solar panels were charging the batteries for a while and the sun disappears behind the clouds or the horizon, the voltage of the batteries might now be a bit different and currents flow between them.
When I have finished using the electric kettle, the voltage of the batteries might now be a bit different and currents flow between them.

I have never measured the equalization currents, but at least I am sure that they were never more than 80 A, because each of my batteries has its own 80 A fuse. What confuses me is that even if they reached 80 A for short times, would that really damage the batteries? I know that the recommendation is to charge a 100 Ah battery with no more than 10 A, but doesn’t my alternator also sometimes charge the battery with up to 80 A, and that doesn’t cause any damage to it?
I also understand the argument that if one battery is a bit older and its full voltage is 12.2 V, while another is newer and its full voltage is 12.8 V, the older one will always drain the newer one down to 12.2 V after they were both charged. Some resources online claim that this is what causes the older battery to deteriorate much faster. But how can that be, given that also the older battery is frequently charged with 14.4 V without being damaged?
Are equalization currents really the reason for my battery failure, and if so, what are the exact mechanisms? Or are there other reasons?

Using batteries in parallel is extremely common and not a problem at all as long as they're the same chemistry (which yours are). How deep did you discharge the three extra batteries while they were separated from the car's main battery? How low did the voltage go?

Equalization current is only an issue when you connect 2 (or more) dissimilarly charged batteries in parallel. Once they've 'equalized' there's no more significant equalization current for as long as they stay connected together.

What do the manufacturers of the batteries say about your circuit topology?

The lowest the voltage went was probably about 11.0 V. The batteries are cheap car batteries, so there is no detailed info from the manufacturer. I should probably add that the system previously had one instead of three additional batteries and worked for years without problems.

FYI: Google for "DC to DC charger." It's the modern way to charge the "house" batteries of a boat or an RV from the engine alternator. Basically, it's a "smart" battery charger/maintainer that runs off your car's 12V system when the engine is running, and which isolates the house batteries when the engine is off. Among its advantages are (A) limits the charging current (there's no "equalization" current) to a sensible value, and (B) house batteries can be a different chemistry (E.g., LiFePO4) from engine starting battery.

"Also while parked, I would often (but not always) turn off the main switch to separate the main battery. . ."  Highly recommended if you are running your telescope clock drive at a remote mountaintop location.  Eventually some bikers came by and got me just enough charge to get started.

Use a meter to heck that there is actual current charging the extra batteries; it is possible that somewhere in the circuit there is a poor connection.  Also, check voltage with the extra batteries isolated, and again with them connected and the engine running.   Sometimes it is hard to make good contact with a car body.

The problem is more fine grained than what first appears.
You have different types of batteries. Your car must have a main starter battery which is intended to be kept almost full all the time, and able to provide the starting current, with hundreds of cold-cranking amps. It is not intended to be deep discharged and used for discharging by powering loads such as water kettles, lamps and laptops.
Your other batteries must be of deep discharge or leisure use types. They are not intended for starting the car but can handle being cycled to deeper discharge levels and charged back up again. These are intended to power your laptops, kettles and interior lamps while not being charged.
Also the wiring between batteries matter, both the sizing of wires and where/how they are connected together with wires. You may think they are wired in parallel, but in reality, you might have first battery connected with wires to solar charger, and a second battery connected with wires to first battery, and that's the worst way of wiring them, unless you use the chassis for unknown return paths. Basically each piece of wire is a resistor, not a superconductor, so the first battery gets charged and discharged most directly, and the seconf battery connects via wire resistances to first battery, so it only partially helps the first battery through wires, and the first battery wears out more than the second battery.
The batteries in a parallel pack must be wired with equal wiring resistance, like for example connecting two batteries together with two identical length and gauge wires, but then connect the solar charger positive terminal to first battery and solar charger negative terminal to second battery. This way the batteries have equal roles in the pack.
Connecting and disconnecting the leisure pack from the car starter battery is a bit of a hazard. If the leisure pack is empty and you flip the switch, tens of amps can flow from starter battery to the leisure pack. Then there will be a significant load even before you use more current to start the car.
Usually you would use some piece of electronic smart charger to handle that, which basically isolates starter battery from leisure battery, but after starting the car, it can charge the leisure pack from the alternator, but in a controlled manner instead of letting just wire resistance limit the current taken from alternator and starter battery to leisure pack.
There must be guides or companies that perform these kinds of installations to camper vans etc, and how it must be done safely and with best practices, so that the installation would pass even basic safety checks. Different parts of the world have difderent legal jurisdictions of course regarding RV/camper 12V wiring and it's not like doing mains voltage electrical work so you don't need an electrician, but at least consider letting a professional do the job for you.

Thanks for the detailed response. I now see some potential flaws in my system: Firstly, I was using regular car batteries but should have used solar batteries that are optimized for deep discharge cycles. However, previously I had the same setup with just one (instead of three) leisure battery and it worked for many years without any major problems (the capacity was slowly degrading, but not as drastically as now). So this cannot explain the sudden failure of the system this time.

Secondly, my parallel wiring is not ideal. All three batteries are connected to a central bus bar, but the lengths of those connecting cables are not equal. As far as I understand, this would cause them to charge unevenly and thus waste a bit of energy, but it wouldn’t cause the system to fail very quickly as it did? Thirdly, using the main switch to connect the starter with the leisure batteries is not ideal, as it causes large currents to flow. But again, this was never a problem previously with just one leisure battery.

If I’m not mistaken a 1m long cable with e.g. 16mmˆ2 cross section only has 1.1mOhm resistance. 80A would only cause a 0.1V drop. Does it really matter if one of your batteries discharges down to 12.2V and the other to 12.3V? Especially if you don’t exceed the current limit of any one of them. And it shouldn’t cause such a quick failure. Of course if OP used thinner wire and had the batteries at both ends of the van it’s a different story. All of it would still only matter if OP pulled high current until the discharge protection triggered.

@Michael The only scenario is a large load drawing a high current (water kettle) for an extended period of time so that the directly connected battery is deep-cycled because the battery-battery connection cannot provide the current at the relatively small voltage difference. But what is deep-cycled? Down to 11V? Down to 60% nominal capacity? That's 40Ah or 480Wh, or 15 minutes of boiling. And some current will flow from the second battery, even extending that time. And any load reduction will let the batteries equal out within minutes.

But yes: Be careful with large loads, have large gauge wires (2AWG?), make sure you do not stress half-empty batteries.

Parallel operation with local alternator voltage sensing should not cause over or under voltage situations assuming the alternator is performing OK.
Most likely scenario is that that a weak battery may have become defective with floating lead particles that reach a density that bridges the battery bank to “bankruptcy” with a short circuit.

Worse yet, "dendrites" form from lead particles like stalactites attracting to stalagmites and will short-circuit one cell then drop 2 volts causing the discharge on the new battery until it fuses open. Then when the dendrite regenerates, the action repeats over and over until even the new battery is dead.  Lesson to learn, monitor the specific gravity of each cell and toss batteries with unequal s.g.

Battery sulphation accelerates when the Vbat drops below 11.5V  This is an overload condition that is OK for 30 sec such as starting a car in winter.
Old batteries will leak and cause a drain so with a light load SOC ranges from 0 to 100% at 11.5 to 12.5V. The evolution of battery death always starts with the weakest cell. Initially, they are perfectly matched but over time one cell becomes weaker by daily charging and discharging faster and overcharging faster, thus accelerating its weakness. It's a classic runaway condition.
This application requires ceramic lead plates in deep-cell batteries and never last long with old car starter batteries even if one is new. These are only meant to operate high currents for a few seconds for 5 or so years every day.  Car start batteries use thin spongy lead to get a high CCA and are not good for 100Ah loads for long periods of time.

It is possible that one of the batteries died because of age and had an issue such as a shorted cell. However, I don’t understand how this could have caused the other batteries to fail. The voltage of the system never dropped below 11.0 V (except temporarily under load while the kettle was running).


while parked, I would often (but not always) turn off the main switch to separate the main battery from the three additional batteries. This would mean that all appliances would only use the three additional batteries, and zero current would be drawn from the main battery. Before starting the car for driving, I would turn on the main switch again.

When you draw from the three additional batteries, without the main battery, you lower the voltage in those batteries, compared to the main battery. When you then reconnect them, a current will flow between the main battery and the 3 additional batteries to equalize the voltage. This equalization flow could be larger than the permissible charge current, and could damage the batteries.
We all know it is common practice for people to "jump start" a car by connecting a healthy battery to a drained battery. Although it works, it isn't good practice, and although fires/explosions from this practice are thankfully infrequent, fires/explosions do happen from this practice. You should NOT make this a regular feature of your battery management. To avoid regrets, batteries should be at the same voltage before being connected in parallel.

If one battery develops e.g. a short circuit cell, it prevents the voltage across the parallel combination from reaching the 13.8 volts or more that allows the other batteries to charge. As a result all the other batteries are left discharged fail in a different manner - sulphating up developing high internal resistance.
Same thing applies with a large capacity battery bank- and a "small charger" even if the charge current is shared across all batteries equally it becomes difficult for the charger to reach the voltage which allows for the batteries to become fully charged.
Also if anything pulls the battery bus voltage below 13.8 volts while trying to charge them , again , the batteries cease to charge. So if you put more than a fraction of the charger output current as a load on the battery bank, the batteries do not reach 100% charge.
Again, sulphation is the end game.
Check your failed batteries - probably one is short circuit cell (low voltage but relatively high capacity) and the rest are sulphated (correct voltage low capacity) .
